# Google App Engine Database : disk usage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, diskspace

I have a Google App engine Application storing 135 MBytes into its datastore, however when I check my quotas It tells me that I'm using 76% of my Free 1gb of stored data.
Is it because of the index ? How can it use so much diskspace?

Thanks

Comment: The amount of space used by your index depends on the kind of indexes you are building.  If you have a complex query that requires a big composite index for every entity it will take up a lot of space.  I believe list properties are also a common culprit.

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to indexes.  Every [property](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property) (with exception of some [types](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#TextProperty)) has "single property" [indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Introduction_to_Indexes) unless you explicitly disable indexing of that property.  Since the indexes store the property name and the value, the impact on storage space can be quite significant.  If you would like statistics on your index usage, star issue [2740](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2740).

If you are using a lot of tasks, your [stored task bytes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits) also counts against your storage usage.  Also note that blobstore usage [counts against](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits) your storage quota.